# How to stop expiration of azure b2c token?

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c

I am working on a xamarin.form project which I am using azure b2c authentication. the token expires after around one hour. 
what should I add to the project to extend the time up to 7-8 hours?
I have used the authentication exactly according to this example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/azure-ad-b2c

Comment: Expiration is handled from the tenant in your b2c console, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the token lifetime on Azure portal.

Azure AD B2C->User flows->your policy->properties

[image]