# Azure B2C: remove token expiration

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm developing Angular app with `@azure/msal-angular`. After long-running (like leaving app for a night) sometimes I get either a timeout exception or interaction exception:
[image]
or
[image]

I configured a timer, that calls `acquireTokenSilent` 30 seconds before the token expires, but it doesn't help:

```
const account = this.msalService.getAccount();
this.startAutoTokenRequest(account.idToken);

...

private startAutoTokenRequest(idToken: any) {
    const authTime = idToken.auth_time || idToken.claims.auth_time;
    const exp = idToken.exp || idToken.claims.exp;

    let seconds = exp - authTime - 30;
    if (seconds < 0) {
      seconds = 1;
    }

    setTimeout(this.renewToken.bind(this), seconds * 1000);
  }

  private renewToken() {
    const params: AuthenticationParameters = {
      authority: environment.b2cPolicies.authorities.signUpSignIn.authority,
      scopes: environment.scopeUri,
      prompt: 'none'
    };
    this.msalService.acquireTokenSilent(params)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(`Successfully generate a new token: ${response.accessToken}.`);

        this.startAutoTokenRequest(response.idToken);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.warn(`There was an error while renewing token: ${error}. Force redirect.`);
        this.msalService.acquireTokenRedirect(params);
      });
  }
```

After a night of running the application, I still need to refresh the page manually. I wonder, is there a way to disable token expiration at all? Or what can be the reason for these issues? My goal is to log in once and be logged in until the user manually logs out.

Maybe it's the same question as this one: [How to stop expiration of azure b2c token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60051695/how-to-stop-expiration-of-azure-b2c-token) but it doesn't answer how to fix my errors, that's why I opened
a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Single Page Apps, your Refresh token (RT) is only valid for 24 hours maximum. See the note [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-tokens?pivots=b2c-user-flow#token-lifetime-behavior).

Calling `acquireTokenSilent()` will attempt to use the RT to get a new Access Token (AT). If that RT has expired, `acquireTokenSilent()` will use a hidden iframe to do a cookie based (AAD B2C web sso cookie) authentication to get a new AT and RT.

The AAD B2C web sso cookie is valid for a maximum of 24hours. If you want it to last longer, you need to use [Keep Me Signed In](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-user-flow#enable-keep-me-signed-in-kmsi).

If the AAD B2C web sso cookie has expired, you will get an exception, and should call loginRedirect().

Comment: If the AAD B2C web sso cookie has expired, you will get an exception, and should call loginRedirect() <- where should I add this loginRedirect() call?

Comment: `.catch(error => {` -> you already have it in the end of your post.